# Extract zip file in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any method to extract zip files and maintain the same folder structure in the output folder.I am able to extract the zip file  and its inner files but not able to extract folder from a zip file and thus fail to maintain folder structure also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There is an AS3 component that allows you to read and write data from zip files, and the demo also shows that it is possible to see the folder structure.

http://www.nochump.com/blog/?p=15

I have not used this component myself, but if I am correct in assuming that you are making an AIR application then this component may automatically generate folders, otherwise you can use the file system api to create the correct folders yourself.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out fzip:

http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/